# Row level select policy on Postgres (greenplum)

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, greenplum, row-level-security

Im using a Greenploum database but im assuming its more or less the same as Postgres. I want to implement a row level security policy based on the value of a column which the table is partitioned by.

I have a table. TABLE rank (id int, rank int, year int, gender char(1), count int, source_system text)

example data: 

`(1,2, 2012, 1,1, source_system_a), 
(2,1, 2012, 1,1, source_system_b), 
(3,4, 2012, 1,1, source_system_a), 
(4,3, 2012, 1,1, source_system_c),`

The table is partitioned based on the source_system column. I want to have a set of users that can see all the data and a set of users that cannot see everything based on the source_system column. source_system_a should be a secure value therefore only those with secure permission should be able to see the row with source_system_a.

for instance,

user a (can see all) does 'select * from rank;'

result: 

`1,2, 2012, 1,1, source_system_a, 
2,1, 2012, 1,1, source_system_b, 
3,4, 2012, 1,1, source_system_a, 
4,3, 2012, 1,1, source_system_c,`

user b (not secure) does 'select * from rank;'

result: 

`2,1, 2012, 1,1, source_system_b, 
4,3, 2012, 1,1, source_system_c,`

Many Thanks

Comment: *"Im using a Greenploum database but im assuming its more or less the same as Postgres"*. It isn't. It's based on a very old version of PostgreSQL that's been dramatically modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greenplum doesn't have Row Level Security (RLS) aside from creating views for different user groups.  If you use a view to dynamically hide rows, there is a way to see the hidden rows so don't do that.

PostgreSQL had the same problem with views until it introduced the security_barrier feature but Greenplum doesn't have this yet.

So for your example, I would create two views:

```
CREATE TABLE rank (id int, rank int, year int, gender char(1), count int, source_system text) DISTRIBUTED BY (id);
CREATE USER user_a;
CREATE USER user_b;

CREATE VIEW vw_rank_a AS SELECT * FROM rank;
CREATE VIEW vw_rank_b AS SELECT * FROM rank WHERE source_system <> 'source_system_a';

GRANT SELECT ON vw_rank_a TO user_a;
GRANT SELECT ON vw_rank_b TO user_b;
```

Comment: Yeah that looks like the best approach until some sort of RLS is adopted. didnt want to have to go down the view approach. Thanks for that!